# Which API i need to call to get Access Token,Consumer Key,Consumer Secret?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

which API needed to call to get Access Token,Consumer Key,Consumer Secret in WSO2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [documentaion](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/AM131/User+Tokens). If you are using 1.3.1, you should call loginapi

Comment: Could u please explain login API under which package and module

Comment: Please provide the path of identity module